# How to mock string variable from a service file in component spec.ts using jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to mock up the screenName value in the component spec.ts file.? Though I mocked the value for screenName in spec file it shows as undefined value only

**sample.service.ts**

```
screenName: string;
```

**sampleComponent.ts**

```js
setScreen(){
  if (sampleService.screenName === 'CREATE'){
  // do this
  } else if (sampleService.screenName === 'View') {
  // do this
  } else {
  // do this
}
```

**samplecomponent.spec.ts**

```js
it('sample Screen as Create', () => {
  limitsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('SampleService', ['screenName']);
  limitsService.screenName = 'CREATE';
  component.setScreen();
  expect(component.setScreen).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the service using useValue in the providers array and then directly use component.sampleService.screenName = 'View' to mock the values

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
    providers: [{ provide: SampleService, useValue: {} }],
  });
  ...
});


it('sample Screen as Create', () => {
  component.sampleService.screenName = 'View';
  component.setScreen();
  expect(component.setScreen).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: yeah i did the same. I overridden the service using "useClass" property.
 {provide: SamleService, useClass: MockSampleService}, and in the mockclass i have hard coded the string value like this
class MockSampleService {
screenName = 'CREATE'
} 
@Mr. Stash